# Animação no Menu usando HTML+CSS

Tags: css, html5

Como eu posso fazer uma animação com o SubMenu de "aparecerendo" e quando ele sumir faça um efeito "desaparecendo" usando CSS?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
  font-family: Roboto;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 5px;
}

.menu ul {
  text-align: center;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li ul {
  width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 0px 10px;
  line-height: 25px;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
}

.menu ul li a {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.menu a {
  padding: 12.5px;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #666666;
}

.menu ul ul {
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.menu ul ul li {
  float: none;
  border-bottom: solid 1px #262626;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul {
  visibility: visible;
}

.menu ul ul a:hover {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  background-color: #262626;
  color: white;
}

.menu a:hover {
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  color: white;
}

.menu ul ul li {
  background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.menu ul ul a {
  font-size: 17px;
}

.menu ul ul li a:hover ul ul ul {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Página Inicial</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Página 2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Página 3</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse caso vc tem que usar `opacity` e não `visibility`. Repare que primeiro eu `.menu ul ul` com opacidade `0` e coloco a propriedade da transição. Já quando faz o hover em `.menu ul li:hover ul` eu coloco a opacidade como `1` e pronto. Agora vc consegue ter a transição do sub-menu aparecendo e depois sumindo

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    font-family: Roboto;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 100px 5px;
}

.menu ul{
    text-align: center;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu ul li ul{
    width: 100%;
}

.menu ul li{
    display:  inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 0px 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.menu ul li a{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.menu a{
    padding: 12.5px;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #666666;
}

.menu ul ul{
    background-color: black;
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 500ms;
}

.menu ul ul li{
    float: none;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #262626;
}

.menu ul li:hover ul{
    opacity: 1;
}

.menu ul ul a:hover{
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    background-color: #262626;
    color: white;
}

.menu a:hover{
    transition: all 0.4s ease;
    color: white;
}

.menu ul ul li{
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
}

.menu ul ul a{
    font-size: 17px;
}

.menu ul ul li a:hover ul ul ul{
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Página Inicial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Página 2</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Página 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">SubMenu2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```